# Rendering points() function on plot in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a Shiny app that plots points on top of a graph. I'm not sure how to make both the plot and points visible at the same time as it appears that only the last renderPlot() is used.

How would I be able to plot both at once?

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {          
  # data
  x <- c(1,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,6,3)
  y <- c(4,5,2,4,2,1,2,5,7,8)
  df <- data.frame(x,y)

  # plot
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(df[[1]],df[[2]]))        
  output$plot <- renderPlot(points(rnorm(200), rnorm(200)))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the data in a `reactiveValues()`. Then update and plot the reactive value data.

Full reproducible example would read:

```
library(shiny)

x <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 3)
y <- c(4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8)

server <- function(input,  output,  session) {          
  global <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(x,  y))

  observeEvent(input$add,{
    global$data <- rbind(global$data, data.frame(x = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20)))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(global$data$x, global$data$y))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I was just wondering about it myself and came up with a different solution.

You can put the `plot()` and the `points()` call together via `list()`. I decided to plot the points in red to help making the distinction.

```r
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {          
  # data
  x <- c(1,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,6,3)
  y <- c(4,5,2,4,2,1,2,5,7,8)
  df <- data.frame(x,y)
  
  # plot                    # use the list() function to put them together
  output$plot <- renderPlot(list(plot(df[[1]],df[[2]],
                                      points(rnorm(200), rnorm(200), col = 2)
                                      )
                                 )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```